# Can an interface nested inside a class be non-static?

Tags: java

I'm reading about some articles[1][2] online about nested interface in Java, I understand that

```
interface A {
    ...
    interface B { // this is static by default
        ...
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure that

```
class C {
    ...
    interface D { // Is this static by default? Why?
        ...
    }
}
```

In short, is that "a nested interface is always static" true?

[1] https://beginnersbook.com/2016/03/nested-or-inner-interfaces-in-java/
[2] https://www.programcreek.com/2013/08/inner-interface-in-java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a non-static inner class is just syntax sugar. A non-static inner class is exactly the same as a standard 'outer' class, with one exception: It has an invisible field of the type of your outer class which is declared `final`. ALL constructors of your inner class have as first parameter the instance of the outer to which this field must be set.. and then there's a biiig sack of syntax sugar thrown all over this to also hide those.

But that's really how it works, and you can use javap to confirm it. So, given:

```
public class Outer { public class Inner {} }
```

versus:

```
public class Outer {}
class Desugared {
    private final Outer outer;
    public Desugared(Outer outer) { this.outer = outer; }
}
```

these things are the same except for syntax:

```
Outer o = new Outer();
o.new Outer.Inner();
```

is the same as:

```
Outer o = new Outer();
new Desugared(o);
```

etcetera.

Here's the thing: interfaces **do not have fields**.

Given that they don't, **they cannot have this hidden field**. And therefore they cannot be 'non-static'. They are therefore implicitly 'static' (they do not have an instance of the outer class implicitly available to them), and you can't change that.

Comment: So a static inner class is a class without the invisible final field you said?

Comment: @LiSeeLeiCow-Q__Q precisely. In general I strongly advise you to always make your inner classes static (and if you need an instance of outer, just make that field explicit, your code will be more readable).

Comment: 'precisely' means yes or no?

Comment: @LiSeeLeiCow-Q__Q precisely means: Yes. I don't know why GhostCat is saying 'no'. Perhaps GhostCat did not properly read your question.

Comment: @LiSeeLeiCow-Q__Q rz is correct about that, I misread your comment/question there. But my other comment holds: I consider it really bad practice to explicitly write something down that is there already. That is like saying: you should write `extends java.lang.Object` on each and any class that doesn't have a different superclass. Such information is *noise*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your "in short" is always true. Quoting directly from the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1):

> A member interface is implicitly static(§9.1.1). It is permitted for the declaration of a member interface to redundantly specify the static modifier.

where "member interface" is defined [shortly before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5):

> A member interface is an interface whose declaration is directly enclosed in the body of another class or interface declaration (§8.1.6, §9.1.4).

Answer (score 1):

Classes *might* be instantiated, interfaces can *not* be instantiated.

Meaning: when you have an inner **class**, you might or might not want to create an instance of that inner class with an "outer" object or not.

Assume you have:

```
class X {
  ... class Y {
```

then both `someInstanceOfX.new Y()` and `new X.Y()` might make sense.

But when you have an inner interface, the **only** use of that interface would be with some other class going `implements C.D`. There is no meaningful way to access `C.D` that would suggest that D should not be static.

Just as your second link says:

> Because an interface can not be instantiated, the inner interface only makes sense if it is static.

Comment: I stuck at static nested class now, is that your `Y` static by default?

Comment: Don't worry, I'll do it later, but I have to first solve all my confusion. Although I upvoted rzwitserloot's answer but I'm still confused after reading your comments...

Comment: This answers makes no sense. This is not, at all, why inner interfaces are inherently static.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Then please explain how you *instantiate* an interface, independent of inner or outer.

Comment: @GhostCat the information in this answer isn't wrong. It's as if you had answered the question with: "The first manned moon landing was on 20th of July 1969". Correct, but unrelated facts.

Comment: @rzwitserloot well, I am wondering if it isn't the other way round. Your argument is based on an implementation detail, and it would rather surprise me if you find anything in the jls that would conceptually uphold your point.

Comment: @rzwitserloot and in fact I can find no such information about what you state in the JLS. Rather All I can find is from [§8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) making the rather terse code comment:  `// Interfaces are never inner`

Comment: Interesting that the variable *declaration* for a field of a (not in-a) static nested class, an inner (non-static) class, and an interface is all the same. It's only when you create a new object of the type that static or not-static comes into play, bolstering @GhostCat's argument.