# Inline implementation of static nested interfaces

Tags: java, android, interface, inner-classes

```
View.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
            //Some code implementing this method
              }
      });
```

Here `OnClickListener` is a static Interface declared inside View. Since it is static, it won't be categorized as an Inner class (correct me if I'm wrong here).

Then how can we use an anonymous class to inline implement this static nested interface?

Since, as I know they are only used to inline implement inner classes which are nested types without the static keyword for enclosed type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: inner interfaces are "static" by default. It is not possible to have an "inner" interface that wouldn't be static! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650365/can-an-interface-nested-inside-a-class-be-non-static/) for some more thoughts on that aspect.

From that point of view, interfaces are just that: interfaces. Doesn't matter if they are a top level interface sitting in their own .java file, or if the interface sits within some class or so.

And any interface can be implemented using an anonymous inner class.

That is really all there is to this.

To answer to the comment:

> so the inline implementation ie the anonymous class itself becomes an inner class of the interface it implements?

No, an anonymous inner class is an inner class of the class that wraps around it. It happens to implement some interface. It is not an inner class of the interface. Inner is really meant in a "physical" sense, as in lines of code sitting *inside* other blocks of code.

```
class Outer {
  class/interface Inner {
```

`Inner` is called an inner class/interface because it lives *inside* `Outer`.